# zend select statement with string

Tags: php, sql, string, zend-framework, select

I've spent 2 hours for just a select statement.

What am I doing wrong?

```
public function fetchSpecific($moderatorid = 1)
    {

        $resultSet = $this->getDbTable()->fetchAll("moderatorid = ".$moderatorid);

        $entries   = array();
        foreach ($resultSet as $row) {
            $entry = new Application_Model_Network();
            $entry->setId($row->id)
                  ->setName($row->name)
                  ->setModeratorId($row->moderatorid);
            $entries[] = $entry;
        }
        return $entries;
    }
```

It is all about this line:

```
$resultSet = $this->getDbTable()->fetchAll("moderatorid = ".$moderatorid);
```

It give me an error likes this:

```
Message: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically that syntax should work, although I would recommend changing it up a bit in order to make sure that your data is properly escaped.  What value do you see for `$moderatorid` when you get that error?  I suspect that variable is generating a syntax error for some reason.

Try this instead:

```
$results = $this->getDbTable()
                ->fetchAll($this->getDbTable()
                                ->getAdapter()
                                ->quoteInto('moderatorid = ?', $moderatorid));
```

This will make sure that `$moderatorid` gets properly escaped and should help prevent syntax errors, and even more importantly it prevents possible SQL injections.

The other issue with using `Zend_Db_Table::fetchAll()` is that when you encounter errors like this, it is difficult to debug the query being executed.

To get around this, construct the `SELECT` statement yourself so you can echo the value if you need to debug the actual SQL being executed.

```
$select = 
$this->getDbTable()
     ->select()
     ->from($this->getDbTable()) // optionally you can specify cols as the 2nd param
     ->where('moderatorid = ?', $moderatorid);

echo $select;  // e.g. SELECT `table`.* FROM `table` WHERE (moderatorid = 1)

$results = $this->getDbTable()->fetchAll($select);
```

Hope that helps you solve your problem.

Some helpful references:
[Zend_Db_Select](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.select.html)
[Zend_Db_Table](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.table.html)